# Ubuntu blocked on startup due to never ending script on startup

Tags: 16.04, scripts, startup

I've added a script called `kafka`, which runs two never ending services (the kafka server and the zookeeper)

I've added this script into `/etc/init.d` 
And also added to the `profile` on the

```
nano ~/.profile
```

Now after I turn on my `Ubuntu`, and write my password, the screen looks like it's locked, waiting for the script to end.

**But now I can't access anything on my virtual machine.**

**QUESTION:**

If there any way to fix this and delete the script I've added?

It stays like this for ever...

[image: locked]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access `tty1`. Once in `tty1`, login with your username and password. Then you can use Nano remove the offending lines. After you have removed them, do:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

---

P.S. Your problem is probably that you didn't put `&` after the command to run the script.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want. By the way, I've put && between command. It should be just one &?

Comment: @waas1919 `&&` means to run the following command if the first completed successfully. A single `&` means to run the command in the background, which is what you want, otherwise it hangs the userspace startup. So for example, what you want is `./script.sh &`